# Swift HTML encoded attributedText gets truncated

Tags: html, ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a HTML string coming through JSON (in a REST call) and the HTML needs to be shown in a UILabel.

Following is the code I am using -

```
let htmlText = info.shortDescription

            if !(htmlText!.isEmpty) {

                var fontAdded: String?

                fontAdded = NSString(format: "<html><body><table><tr><td><span style=\"font-family: Lato; font-size: 14; margin: 0; padding: 0;\">%@</span></td></tr></table><br><br><br><br><br></body></html>", htmlText!) as String

                if let htmlData = fontAdded!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) {
                    do {
                        headerView.bodyLabel.attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],documentAttributes: nil)

                    } catch let e as NSError {
                        print("Couldn't translate \(htmlText): \(e.localizedDescription) ")
                        headerView.bodyLabel.text = info.shortDescription
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                headerView.bodyLabel.text = info.shortDescription
            }
```

So, whenever I receive a HTML string, for e.g. if it contains Bold/Italics tags, then the UILabel shows text with whatever styling is applied in the HTML string.

**The problem:-**
The last few lines in the HTML string are truncated. 
Note that there is no constraint that is blocking the UI to display the whole text. 
To my `fontAdded`, if I add more number of `<br>` tags, then the whole text is visible and there is no truncation issue. But the HTML string can be of any size and can be changed any time. I do not want to hardcode it by adding **`<br>`**s

I also used `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` but there is no difference in the result. Moreover, the special characters that I receive are not working properly when I use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Could someone help on this issue?

Comment: you can use the web view to show the HTML code

Comment: @AbdulKarim: Not a feasible solution at this moment, since I have to go through many approval processes to make a change in the existing implementation. :-(

Comment: ok .. so can you show the output result as an image, so that I can understand properly and help you out

Comment: HTML data as image? I didn't get you.

Comment: if possible can you show the output you are getting on ios screen and how you exactly you want to show them. @Lohith Korupolu

Comment: @Lohith Korupolu : What are the constraints on UILabel ??

Comment: @SandeepBhandari: I just have the top, right, bottom, left spacing constraints. (19, 8, 8, 8). Will that be a problem? Should I add anything else?

Comment: @lohith-korupolu : Yup :) See how auto layout works is by forming and solving mathematical equations :) As you said you have 8 px constraint to bottom, assume if your view is 250px and you have simply one label which has 8 px top + 8px bottom constraint, so label can at max at 250 - (8 +8) = 234px correct ?? Now labels have implicit size, that means they decide their size based on content they hold, now if you add more content which makes them to have height greater than 234px it will truncate text :)

Comment: @lohith-korupolu : What you can do :) Replace label with textview and let it scroll content :) Or add a height constraint to label and then calculate the estimated text height and update labels height constraint :) Lemme know which solution is fine to u lemme provide u the code for the same :)

Comment: but the label increases in height when I keep adding <br>s. But now, what constraints do I need to add?

Comment: I tried replacing my label with textView before I posted the question here but with same constraints. May be that was wrong I tried.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari: Thank you.. your comment about constraints made me think in that direction. I got it working now by setting the bottom constraint to 0. And, added a height constraint with 100 and "Greater than or Equal" Relation :-)
And, when there is empty HTML, I am setting this constraint to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe could set the paragraph style of your attributed string:

```
let psSpace = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
psSpace.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

NSAttributedString(data: htmlData,
                   options: [[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], psSpace],
                   documentAttributes: nil)
```

like so for **Swift 3**

Comment: doesn't help :(

Comment: And your `Line Break` for the label is probably also set to word wrap or so?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.. your comments and inputs about constraints made me think in that direction. I got it working now by setting the bottom constraint to 0. And, added a height constraint with 100 and "Greater than or Equal" Relation :-) And, when there is empty HTML, I am setting this constraint to 0